# RETROFIT: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

currently running into an issue after updating my gradle file of retrofit from beta2 to the current beta4. I am receiving the error shown in the title, however, this @POST method worked before but isn't currently working after the update and i cant quite put my finger on what is going wrong. Thanks in Advance for your help.

```
public interface UserApi {
    String baseUrl = "some url";


    @POST("users")
    Call<User> postJson(@Body User user);


    class Factory{


        private static UserApi service;
        public static UserApi getInstance(){

            if(service == null){
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
                service = retrofit.create(UserApi.class);
                return service;
            }else{
                return service;
            }
        }
    }
}








public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Bind(R.id.register_password) EditText mPass;
    @Bind(R.id.confirm_password) EditText mConfirm;
    @Bind(R.id.register_firstName) EditText mFirstName;
    @Bind(R.id.register_lastName) EditText mLastName;
    @Bind(R.id.register_email) EditText mEmail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

    }

    @OnClick(R.id.register_button)
    public void Registration() {
        if (!(mPass.getText().toString().equals(mConfirm.getText().toString()))) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Passwords Do Not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (mPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Password Field is Blank, Enter a Valid Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            String password = mPass.getText().toString();
            String confirmPass = mConfirm.getText().toString();
            String firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString();
            String lastName = mLastName.getText().toString();
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            User user = new User(firstName, lastName, email, password);

            UserApi.Factory.getInstance().postJson(user).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    Log.v("Did it work? ", "Yes it did work");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.v("No Dice", t.getMessage());
                }

            });
            Intent login = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }

    }
}
```

The Error:

```
02-24 20:51:53.340 16889-16889/com.example.android.todotracker V/No Dice: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: perhaps you'd be better off figuring out what's causing the json to be corrupted, rather than trying to parse potentially bad data.

Comment: I cant see what could actually be causing an issue with the way it is being posted because as i said in the OP, This Exact method worked with the gradle builds below perfectly fine. :

compile "com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2"
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'                       Currently i am using compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4' and compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4" which is now giving me this issue

Comment: post your malformed json. (also, consider fixing it)

Comment: Wasnt anything wrong with the json, was an issue with spring security. Problem solved